# Column Level Encryption in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, encryption

When using the column level encryption approach, do we need to explicitly close the symmetric key in stored procedures/views or its not required? how it's handled for the subsequent openings ?

eg:

```
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SQLSymmetricKey
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking into consideration the remarks of [CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/close-symmetric-key-transact-sql) (highlighting mine)

> **Open symmetric keys are bound to the session not to the security
>   context.** An open key will continue to be available until it is either
>   explicitly closed or the session is terminated.

Security best practices usually suggest having a security mechanism (symmetric key) open for the minimum amount of time that is it necessary and only in the scope (stored procedure) necessary.

Referencing the example code in [DECRYPTBYKEYAUTOCERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/decryptbykeyautocert-transact-sql), there are basically two ways to decrypt column encrypted data.

**OPTION ONE**

- Typically what you'd do in a stored procedure where you open the key,
  decrypt the data using `DecryptByKey` and then close the key before
  returning control.

**OPTION TWO**

- Can be used in a view that utilizes the `DecryptByKeyAutoCert`
  function to automatically decrypt the data without having to
  explicitly open the key.  (*Requires VIEW DEFINITION permission on the symmetric key and CONTROL permission on the certificate.*)

---

```
--Create the keys and certificate.  
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'mzkvdlk979438teag$$ds987yghn)(*&4fdg^';  
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'mzkvdlk979438teag$$ds987yghn)(*&4fdg^';  
CREATE CERTIFICATE HumanResources037   
   WITH SUBJECT = 'Sammamish HR',   
   EXPIRY_DATE = '10/31/2009';  
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SSN_Key_01 WITH ALGORITHM = DES  
    ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE HumanResources037;  
GO  
----Add a column of encrypted data.  
ALTER TABLE HumanResources.Employee  
    ADD EncryptedNationalIDNumber varbinary(128);   
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SSN_Key_01  
   DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE HumanResources037 ;  
UPDATE HumanResources.Employee  
SET EncryptedNationalIDNumber  
    = EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('SSN_Key_01'), NationalIDNumber);  
GO  
--  
--Close the key used to encrypt the data.  
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SSN_Key_01;  
--  
--There are two ways to decrypt the stored data.  
--  
--OPTION ONE, using DecryptByKey()  
--1. Open the symmetric key  
--2. Decrypt the data  
--3. Close the symmetric key  
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SSN_Key_01  
   DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE HumanResources037;  
SELECT NationalIDNumber, EncryptedNationalIDNumber    
    AS 'Encrypted ID Number',  
    CONVERT(nvarchar, DecryptByKey(EncryptedNationalIDNumber))   
    AS 'Decrypted ID Number'  
    FROM HumanResources.Employee;  
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SSN_Key_01;  
--  
--OPTION TWO, using DecryptByKeyAutoCert()  
SELECT NationalIDNumber, EncryptedNationalIDNumber   
    AS 'Encrypted ID Number',  
    CONVERT(nvarchar, DecryptByKeyAutoCert ( cert_ID('HumanResources037') , NULL ,EncryptedNationalIDNumber))   
    AS 'Decrypted ID Number'  
    FROM HumanResources.Employee;
```